# Showing my app in all spaces even if 'Every Space' is selected

Tags: macos, launch, spaces

I am developing an Mac Desktop application. I have the problem related to Spaces for my App. I have added to show my App in all spaces using the System Preference option Application Assignments-Space as 'Every Space'. It works fine until I restart my app. Once I restart my app, it is shown only in the space where it is launched even if the System Preferene option shows 'Every Space'.

Do I need to update application settings for this to work. What is the problem here. Could someone help me?

Regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces];

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I will try this out and post the answer here.